# Recommended Pre-Processing Steps For SURF Feature Extraction

Tags: image-processing, surf

Are there any recommended pre-processing steps to perform before extracting SURF features from an image? For example, lighting / color balance, histogram equalization, etc.?

Comment: It is too broad question. Could you post example of image you want to process and specify what do you want to archive? Basically, try to use SURF without any pre-processing and check if results are not satisfactory for you - SURF shows good performance without any preprocessing for many images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general no preprocessing required to extract SURF.
 Lightning is normalized inside build of surf descriptors.
 Perpixel noise is not important , cause SURF use big enough processing windows. 
 SURF itself designed to be robust to some extrinsic noises.